# .sh started by cron does not create file via python

Tags: python, shell, cron

I have this .sh which starts a python file. This python file generates a .txt when started via the commandline with sudo but doesn't when started via the .sh

Why doesn't the pyhton file give me a .txt when started with the cron and .sh?

When I use `su -c "python /var/www/html/readdht.py > /var/www/html/dhtdata.txt" 2>&1 >/dev/null`, .sh gives me output, but omits the newlines, so I get one big string.

The python file creates a .txt correctly when started from the commandline with `sudo python readdht.py`.

If the .sh the python file is started with `su -c "python /var/www/html/readdht.py` no .txt is created

What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to answer without more colour on your environment.

Here's how to solve this though: do not redirect your output to /dev/null. Then read in your cron log what happened. It seems very likely that your script fails, and therefore does not return anything to standard out, so does not create a file.

I highly suspect it is because you are using a python module, or python version or python path that is loaded in your bashrc. Crontab does not execute your bashrc, it's an independent environment, so you cannot assume that a script that runs correctly when you manually launch will work in your cron.

Try sourcing your bashrc in your cron task, and it's very likely to solve your problem.